# SyntaxError: invalid syntax with with open

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to write to a json file but this line gives me syntax error

`with open("tries.json", "w") as f:`

"SyntaxError: invalid syntax" is the exact is the exact error

Whole code that should be relevant to this

```
with open("tries.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
if data["code"]["ended"] == True:
    await ctx.send("This event has already ended")
else:
    if data["code"][str(ctx.author.id)]["tries"] > 0:
        if data["code"][str(ctx.author.id)["correct"] == False:
            with open("tries.json", "w") as f:
                del data["code"][str(ctx.author.id)]
                update = {
                    ctx.author.id: {"tries": 1, "correct": True}
                }
                data["code"].update(update)
                json.dump(data, f)
                f.close()
            await ctx.send("**Now you need to use Caesar's Cipher. Use ~answer [code] to take the prize. Every capital letter is required. You have only 1 attempt for this command. Take your time! Hint: the answer contains real words**")
        else:
            await ctx.send("**You've already answered correctly**")
```

I couldn't find anything helpful anywhere so I hope I get help from this, thank you!

Comment: you have missing closing bracket ] on the previous line  `if data["code"][str(ctx.author.id)]["correct"] == False:`

Answer (score 1):

```
if data["code"][str(ctx.author.id)["correct"] == False:
```

You are missing a `]`.

It should be

```
if data["code"][str(ctx.author.id)]["correct"] == False:
```

Comment: So close as a typo?

Comment: Thank you lot, somehow I missed this completely